# select query for table having a same value

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure Like this

```
id  prid    tyid

1    2        3   
2    2        1    
3    4        5      
4    4        2    
5    1        3
```

If `prid =2` then 
I only want 3 & 1 in single row.

Comment: Plea post code you have tried

Comment: which property 'type'? and what exactly is 3 & 1?

Comment: please describe your question properly

Answer (score 1):

Use

## [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
Select id,prop_id,Group_ConCat(tyid) AS Tid 
From table where prop_id = 2
Group By prid
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81a146/3)

Comment: after using this query the type_id which i found in this columnGroup_ConCat(type_idfrom),how can i used this for further process

Comment: where do you want to use this? as per your requirements this query gives the result in a single row! which was your question

Comment: this query is working thank u so much...:)

Comment: use markful if its helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
Select prop_id, Group_ConCat(type_id) AS Tid 
From tbl 
Group By prop_id order by prop_id
```

This will output your expected requirement with order by prop_id

Comment: How exactly this differs from Hanky's answer? other that a sort?